# Need little help on understanding how starting index and substring works

Tags: java, substring, indexof

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Type a word: ");
    String userWord = reader.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Length of the first part: ");
    int userLength = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Result: " + userWord.substring(0, userLength));
}
```

Result:

```
Type a word: hellothere
Length of the first part: 3
Result: hel
```

Starting index starts counting from 0 right? So shouldn't the result print "hell"?

0 = h

1 = e

2 = l

3 = l

Comment: Why not read the Javadoc of `substring`?

Comment: "The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`"

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `substring()` is an exlusive index. Means: When you enter 3 it will give you only the letters until index 2. This isn't one of the most obvious methods in the Java API, but should be well documented.